# Breadth first traversal of a binary tree in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a breadth first traversal method for Binary Trees in Java. I've referenced multiple examples here and none have seemed to help.

```
public String breadthFirstTraverse(){
    MyQueue<BinaryNode<T>> travQ = new MyQueue<BinaryNode<T>>();
    MyQueue<T> mq = new MyQueue<T>();
    if(root == null){
        return "";
    }
    mq.enqueue(root.getData());
    travQ.enqueue(root);
    BinaryNode<T> node = root;
    while(travQ.size() != 0){
        node = travQ.dequeue();
        if (node.getLeftNode().getData() != nullSymbol){
            mq.enqueue(node.getLeftNode().getData());
            travQ.enqueue(node.getLeftNode());
        }
        if (node.getRightNode().getData() != nullSymbol){
            mq.enqueue(node.getRightNode().getData());
            travQ.enqueue(node.getRightNode());
        }
    }
    return mq.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void printBFS(TreeNode root){
    Deque<TreeNode> a=new ArrayDeque<TreeNode>();
    a.addLast(root);
    while(!a.isEmpty()){
        TreeNode t=a.removeFirst();
        System.out.println(t.payload);
        if(t.left!=null){
            a.addLast(t.left);
        }
        if(t.right!=null){
            a.addLast(t.right);

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit your code properly so that it all fits in one grey block

Answer (score -1):

With java 8 syntax

```
void bfsTraverse(Node node, Queue<Node> tq) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(" " + node.value);
    Optional.ofNullable(node.left).ifPresent(tq::add);
    Optional.ofNullable(node.right).ifPresent(tq::add);
    bfsTraverse(tq.poll(), tq);
}
```

Then invoke this method with root Node and a new object of Queue interface implementation

```
bfsTraverse(root, new LinkedList<>());
```

Comment: [Don't use Optionals for conditional logic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235329/5515060)

Comment: @Lino What is the drawback? It does the same with more elegant way

Comment: @Lino For me I don't like null checks with if. Voting down answers for your personal preference, is not nice.

Comment: Using `Optional` creates unnecessary objects. The method references are fairly advanced programming stuff that can be done shorter in traditional, basic code. Even though `if (node.left != null) tq.add(node.left);` repeats `node.left`, it is still shorter.