# replace two ternary operator by java 8 optional expression

Tags: java, option-type

I want to replace two ternary operator by a java 8 optional expression

Here is the two ternary operator:

valueA and valueB are string

```
valueA != null ? valueA.length() < 3 ? "0"+valueA : valueA : valueB
```

how to do it ?

Comment: First change the inner ternary as an optional and then the outer. Maybe perhaps it would be a good idea for readability to split them to different lines also?

Comment: the methods: `ofNullable()`, `.filter()`, `.map()` and `.orElse()` are your friends here. I suggest you to look at the javadoc of each to understand how you should use them

Comment: Also: [Don't use Optionals for conditional logic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235329/5515060)

Comment: In case you are trying to create an octal escape, mind that sometimes you even need to prepend `"00"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(valueA)
    .map(s -> s.length() < 3 ? "0" + s : s)
    .orElse(valueB);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Optional` class *wraps* a null or an object. Using `Optional` does not eliminate the nulls, nor can it replace your ternary tests. However, an `Optional` may simplify your ternaries: see [Answer by saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66578806/642706).

You could simply call `Optional.ofNullable` and pass the result of your nested ternary tests.

```
Optional < String > optional = 
    Optional.ofNullable( 
        valueA != null ? valueA.length() < 3 ? "0" + valueA : valueA : valueB 
    ) 
;
```

(Replace `String` with your particular data type in code above.)

As I read your ternaries, any of five outcomes are possible:

- null (where `valueA` is null)
- `valueA`
- modified `valueA`
- `valueB` having an object
- `valueB` being null

Our call to `Optional.ofNullable` handles all five.

- If null, an empty `Optional` is returned.
- If non-null, a `Optional` containing an object is returned.

---

As [Lino commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578562/replace-two-ternary-operator-by-java-8-optional-expression/66578738#comment117695885_66578562), [the original purpose to the `Optional` class was for use as the return type of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/5515060), to signal when null is a legitimate value rather a problem (error, unknown, etc.). While you are free to use `Optional` in other ways, doing so is likely to be a poor choice.

Comment: The only case handled by the `Optional` in your code is the last one, `valueB` being null. Everything else is still handled by the ternary operator.