# What would be the best approach for this Java null check? Should I use an Optional?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I want to achieve the following:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
linkedHashMap.put("someString", object.getObjectField().getValue());
```

If `object.getObjectField()` is null, then I get a `NullPointerException`. I can easily avoid it, with the following null check:

```
if(object.getObjectField() != null) {
    linkedHashMap.put("someString", object.getObjectField().getValue());
    } else {
    linkedHashMap.put("someString", "N/A");
}
```

However, I was thinking to find a better and prettier implementation, using Java 8 Optional, but in this case I still receive a `NullPointerException`:

```
linkedHashMap.put("someString", Optional.ofNullable(object.getObjectField().getValue()).orElse("N/A");
```

What would be the right approach in this case?

Comment: You *could* use the ternary operator: `linkedHashMap.put("someString", object.getObjectField() == null ? "N/A" : object.getObjectField().getValue());`

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235254/optional-vs-if-else-if-performance-java-8/56235329#56235329) if not the dupe. [Another candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional/23464794#23464794). (didn't close because its my answer on the first one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in this case I still receive a NullPointerException

That's because you would still be invoking `getValue()` even if `getObjectField()` is null.

You can use `Optional.map` to apply a function if present:

```
Optional.ofNullable(object.getObjectField()).map(ObjectType::getValue)
```

If you want to use a default value, you can just add the `orElse` after that:

```
Optional.ofNullable(object.getObjectField()).map(ObjectType::getValue)
    .ofElse("N/A")
```